Why is CP-SAT Slower? Comparing Performance of CP-SAT and Original Solver for N-Queens Problem in Python with OR-Tools
I am currently working on solving the N-Queens problem in Python (version 3.12) using OR-Tools. Specifically, I'm experimenting with both the CP-SAT solver and the original solver provided by OR-Tools.
For the CP-SAT solver, I've utilized the code provided in the official Google documentation, available here. Similarly, for the original solver, I've referred to the code provided in the same documentation here.
However, I've encountered significant differences in performance between the two solvers. For example when solving for 12 queens on the board, here are the observed times:
time python queens-original.py

Statistics
  failures: 116806
  branches: 262010
  wall time: 688 ms
  Solutions found: 14200
python queens-original.py  0.72s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.736 total

time python queens-cp-sat.py  

Statistics
  conflicts      : 133465
  branches       : 708019
  wall time      : 10.891582737 s
  solutions found: 14200
python queens-cp-sat.py  11.59s user 0.62s system 106% cpu 11.424 total

To streamline the comparison process, I've omitted the sections responsible for printing the results in both scripts.
My question is twofold:
Why does the original solver demonstrate significantly better performance compared to the CP-SAT solver for this specific problem instance?
Are there any optimizations or adjustments that can be made to the CP-SAT implementation to improve its performance and make it more competitive with the original solver?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried solving the N-Queens problem using both the CP-SAT and original OR-Tools solvers, following the Google documentation. With 12 queens, the original solver performed significantly faster than CP-SAT, contrary to my expectations. I'm seeking insights into why CP-SAT was slower and any potential optimizations.

This was asked before.
The short answer, we do not care about nqueens. It does not reflect any useful problem.
It does not test the ability of the solver to find hard solutions, or to prove optimality. It just test the speed of the solver to crunch nodes and to read variable domains.
In these aspects, CP-SAT is way slower than the original cp solver. But on real problems, reading domains or crunching nodes never appears when profiling, so there are no incentive to optimize this aspect of the solver.
